# When I make a POST request to my back-end and try to access the body, every property is converted to string, including arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just realized that when I make a POST request like this:

```
    async createProduct(){
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name", "test")
        formData.append("price", 150)
        formData.append("brands", [1, 2])

        let response = await axios.post("/createProduct", formData)
    }
```

And then console.log() the typeof each property on the back-end, I always get a string:

```
console.log(typeof req.body.brands) --> String 1, 2
console.log(typeof req.body.price) --> String 150
```

Why is this happening and how can I turn them to their original data types? I guess I can turn the `req.body.price` to integer with parseInt(), but how to turn `req.body.brands` back to an array?

Comment: you can convert it to array using eval() function

Comment: for conversion `req.body.brands.split(',')` split the String with comma

Comment: and the reson it is string is because you have only two data type available. check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: Why are you using FormData ? Any particular reason ? I would just stick to plaine json and only use FormData when necessary, like FileUpload.

Comment: @PascalLamers Oh I am using FormData because I'm actually file uploading, it's just that I assumed it's irrelevant to my question and didn't include it

Comment: What body parser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using something like `multer` as a body parser to handle form-data.

You are adding the array wrong. The `formData.append()` function only accepts a string as argument. This causes `[1,2]` to be converted to a string automatically which conveniently is equal to `[1,2].join(', ')`.

However, form-data does indeed support multiple values which `multer` will parse into arrays. But note that it support multiple values. Not arrays. So the correct syntax to add an array of values is:

```
formData.append("brands", 1);
formData.append("brands", 2);
```

Or more generally:

```
[1,2].forEach(x => formData.append("brands", x));
```

Doing this your backend should correctly parse the values into an array:

```
console.log(typeof req.body.brands) --> Array [1,2]
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is very confusing. How do you console.log() on the back-end?
If you meant, front-end and you are using PHP or whatever, if you receive an object response, you still have to convert it to your desired data type.

For JSON
`var a = JSON.parse(response)`

Then if you're expecting an array,
you should make the response an array type in the server. That way, Javascript will automatically detect it as an array.
`console.log(response.length)`

If you want convert your data to array in the server:
`$data = array(1,2,3);`

Then ensure you use a proper encoding type to flush response back to the HTML page.
`echo json_encode($data);`

---

If you already have your data and want to convert it to an array, do this:

````
   var arr = [];
   var data = response.split(',');
   
   //Loop through data
   for(var x=0;x < data.length;x++) {
     arr.push(data[x]);
   }


   console.log(typeof arr) //Array (Object)```


Ordinarily, The ```arr = arr.split(',');```
is already an array and can be worked on
````

Comment: He is doing `console.log` in the backend because obviously that's how you log in javascript. Have you not used node.js before?

Comment: Also note that he cannot use `json_encode()` because javascript does not have that function. You need to do `JSON.stringify()` on the backend.